# Vue directive not compiling after being inserted by javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm inserting entries into a `<ul>` element via vue and javascript. In one of the entries, a icon with an @click directive is inserted, however, when it shows up in the source code, it literally shows the @click directive and the click does nothing. Below is an example of the code. I think the line is not being compiled? How would I get the ability to add in the HTML to the dom as well as have that @click directive work?

```
validateData: function() {
            this.loading = true;
            axios.post('/validate-data', this.$data.model)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response);
                    var select_opt = 1;

                        var email = $('#email').val();
                        var address = document.querySelector('.input_description').value;
                        var name = document.querySelector('.input_title_desc').value;
                        var phone = $('#phone').val();



                        var class_li  =['list_shopping list_dsp_none','list_work list_dsp_none','list_sport list_dsp_none','list_music list_dsp_none'];

                        var cont = '<div class="col_md_1_list"><p id="phone_' + contador + '">'+phone+'</p></div><div class="col_md_2_list"><h4 id="name_' + contador + '">'+name+'</h4><p id="address_' + contador + '">'+address+'</p></div><div class="col_md_3_list"><div class="cont_text_date"><p id="email_' + contador + '">'+email+'</p></div><div class="cont_btns_options"><i @click="sendSMS('+contador+')" class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-2x" style="color: #6d696f; position: absolute; left:-13px; cursor:pointer;"></i><ul><li><i onclick="finish_action(' + select_opt + ',' + contador + ')"<i class="far fa-times-circle fa-2x" style="color: indianred; position: absolute; right: -32px; cursor: pointer;"></i></li></ul></div></div>';

                        var li = document.createElement('li');
                        li.className = class_li[select_opt]+" li_num_"+contador;

                        li.innerHTML = cont;
                        document.querySelectorAll('.cont_princ_lists > ul')[0].appendChild(li);
                        setTimeout(function(){  document.querySelector('.li_num_'+contador).style.display = "block";
                        },100);

                        setTimeout(function(){
                            document.querySelector('.li_num_'+contador).className = "list_dsp_true "+class_li[select_opt]+" li_num_"+contador;
                            contador++;
                        },200);
                    $('#email').val('');
                    $('.input_description').val('');
                    $('.input_title_desc').val('');
                    $('#phone').val('');
                    this.model.name = '';
                    this.model.phone = '';
                    this.model.email = '';
                    this.model.address = '';
                    this.loading = false;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    this.errors.record(error.response.data.errors);
                    this.loading = false;
                });
```

This is the line in question:

```
<i @click="sendSMS('+contador+')" class="fas fa-mobile-alt fa-2x" style="color: #6d696f; position: absolute; left:-13px; cursor:pointer;"></i>
```

That line does not get 'compiled' properly and appears in the DOM as literal string and the button does nothing.

Comment: Vue doesn't know anything about the HTML you're injecting into the DOM; you're going to have to unlearn the habit of touching the DOM directly if you want to use Vue (or any other modern SPA framework).  Put this html in the Vue component template instead, and use `v-if` to control when it appears; and read data from the component data scope instead of directly from form fields in the DOM.

Comment: I'm seeing that now. Wondering if I should create a component or if I can just use a data variable array to hold the entries.

Comment: Not much point in including vue if you’re going to work around the framework instead of using it. Make a component.

Comment: @DanielBeck Created a template and now everything is working perfectly. Thanks!